# How do I set text Background colour with the PDF::API2 Perl module?

Tags: perl

I want to use text background or highlight colour using `PDF::API2`. How I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "highlight colour".

PDF documents have no "background" as such.You must draw a page-sized rectangle on each page and set its fill colour to the desired value.

Something like this should work for you, but I'm unable to test it at the moment.

Of course, you'll have to combine it sensibly with your existing code and make sure that the background content that contains the coloured rectangle is created before anything else

```
my $page = $pdf->page;

my $bg_content = $page->gfx;

my ($blx, $bly, $trx, $try) = $page->get_mediabox;

my $bg_rect = $bg_content->rect($blx, $bly, $trx-$blx, $try-$bly);
$bg_rect->fillcolor('blue');
$bg_rect->fill;
```